# Setting up contracts for Paid App?

Tags: iphone, contract

I'm trying to setup a contract in iTunes Connect, but all I have is the free contract. I don't have the option to setup a new contract.

Anyone any ideas why ?

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, just logged out and back in again. All options there now.